# How can I limit the maximum number of running processes within Microsoft Windows?

Tags: windows, process, registry

I'm looking for a way to limit the maximum number of running processes in Windows Server 2003.

Is there a registry key somewhere that controls it?
If so, which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are talking about processes as in the items listed in task manager, then there is no way to do it natively, and you can do it with a program, ***but there should be no real valid reason to do so.***

If you are talking about making your application only ever launch one EXE no matter how many times it is called, then you are looking for singleton-ing. Example for .NET at: http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/SingleInstance.aspx --EDIT For another language, google for "singleton" and your language.

If you are asking about something else, please elaborate.

Comment: "Singleton" is the wrong thing to Google - most hits will be for the Singleton design pattern :(

Comment: ... "singleton java"... "Singleton vb.net"

Answer (score 0):

Domestic retail Windows has no intrinsic way of limiting the number of processes (other than exhausting available resources)

Windows Starter Editions achieved process capping with a modified version of Windows- Starter ed. is only available in emerging markets however.